# How to drop and then recreate database with pg-promise?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I would like to be able to reset my database from code by first dropping the database, then recreating it, then recreating all the tables, then repopulating it with data.

But if I simply do this:

```
await db.any('DROP DATABASE $1',cn.database)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: syntax error at or near "'testdb'"
```

Most likely because I'm attempting to delete the database I'm currently connected to.

So is there a way to delete or reset a database with pg-promise at runtime?

Comment: well, fairly obviously to connect to a different database.

Comment: "*because I'm attempting to delete the database I'm currently connected to*" - no, it's a syntax error, not an execution error.

Comment: @RichardHuxton does this mean I need to add an empty sidestep DB to every server? seems kind of bad practice. Can't I just somehow exist the current db, like on the command line?

Comment: Life is simpler if you just drop the tables, and recreate those. Dropping the database itself requires use of connection for a different database, because you cannot drop a database to which you are connected.

Comment: I found out you can just not pass a database to pgp and it will connect on the top level. This requires a seperate connection but it works

Comment: There is no "top level", it just connects to the default database, as set within `pgp.pg.defaults.database`. See [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg/lib/defaults.js#L11).

Comment: @vitaly-t Dropping all tables requires knowing which tables there are, and often enough misses functions, sequences, types, custom operators and whatnot. What I found to be a good compromise is dropping and recreating the schema(s) that the application was using, which catches most database objects (but not extensions, events, collations, replications and other database-level configuration)

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, you're right :)

Comment: @vitaly-t pgp.pg.defaults.database is undefined both in the code you linked and in my code.

Comment: @user2741831 Yes, sorry, it defaults to database `postgres` then. Or to be accurate, it uses the same database as the user name - see [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js#L63).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database name is an identifier, not a value literal, in SQL syntax. You need to use an [SQL Name filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names):

```js
await db.none('DROP DATABASE $1~', cn.database);
// or
await db.none('DROP DATABASE $1:name', cn.database);
// or
await db.none('DROP DATABASE ${database:name}', cn);
```

Comment: thanks, but now I just get the proper error  "cannot drop the currently open database". But out of curiosity, are the strings sanitized, meaning I don't have to worry about sql injections?

Comment: @user2741831 That's what the pg-promise library's filters do, yes - it's not like `'DROP DATABASE ' + cn.database`.

Comment: @user2741831 "*now I just get the proper error "cannot drop the currently open database"*" - as RichardHuxton remarked, to drop a database you need to be connected to a different database, typically the ["maintenance" database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269878/188406) of the cluster